# How to enlarge image without overlapping other elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My images in desktop view https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/ are flat. Want to increase their height so they look great in desktop too. However, 2 points.

One, can't seem to find the correct css selector. 
Two, can't seem to do it without it overlapping other elements.

I just want it to make it taller (proportionally of course)

Html:

```
<form class "event_filters" id class="event_filters" >....</form>
<div class="event-listing-view-header"></div>
<ul class="event_listings event-listings-table-bordered-change 
event-listings-change" id ="event-listing-view">
<div class="line-layout" style="display: none;">
</h4><div class="boxes-view-listing-registered-code"></div></div>
<div class="events-organizer-name">....</div></div>
<div class="col-md-2">....</div>
<div class="col-md-3">....</div>
<div class="col-md-2">....</div>
<div class="col-md-3">....</div>
</div>
```

Tried css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {.box-layout.event-img img {height: 200px; width: 400px;}}
```

Nothing....

Comment: There are no images on your html.

Comment: Ok. You caught me...:-) I'm accessing this from mobile so can't see full html through mobile view-source...

Comment: Whenever you can post your full html edit your question please.

Comment: Ok sure sure. Will do. Thanks for the advice....

Comment: The css selector it seems like you are looking for is `.box-layout .event-img img` (with a space after box-layout class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are looking for, but I would try something like this:

Using the css selector `.box-layout .event-img img` and `object-fit:cover`to prevent distorting the images.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .box-layout .event-img img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

Edit: To fix the overlapping text and image you need to remove the heights for `.box-layout .event-img` selector (or override them if you don't have access to change)

```
.box-layout .event-img {
    display: table-cell;
    /* height: 100px; */
    /* max-height: 100px; */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

In order to override the CSS you can add:

```
.box-layout .event-img { 
  height: initial; 
  max-height: initial; 
}
```

This needs to be added in a stylesheet (or on page) after `frontend.min.css` is included on the page.

Comment: Ah, thanks. You mean the reason why it wasn't working as a selector was that there was no space between the dot and the div? Or just that i didn't use `object-fit`?

Comment: Correct, the selector was not working because of the lack of a space. `object-fit` was just a suggestion to make it look a bit better.

Comment: Thanks. So if you view the page now, you can see that the selector worked but it's overlapping the text whereas it should push everything below it down, if that makes sense? https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/....... desktop view....

Comment: I updated my answer to include a fix for that. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks. Should I unset the parts in grey so as to remove height?

Comment: Thanks for the code, the edit, and your gracious efforts in helping me. Just to let you know, I tried the edit and it doesn't seem to have effected anything. It also said that `float` can't be used with `table-cell`....?

Comment: Check the classes/selectors you are using, I was modifying in the inspector and the edit I posted is only commenting out css that is already applied. The two lines commented out in the edit need to be removed. If you haven't before, I would highly recommend learning the developer tools/inspector for the browser you are using.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what it looks like when you comment out the two css lines. If that is what you are looking for, make sure you aren't loading a cached css file.

Comment: You total pro... Where do i find it? Or can i just do unset? Presumably not as its php...?

Comment: The CSS is located in `frontend.min.css`. If you are the one responsible for generating that css file, you can just change it in there. If not, just add the following css: `.box-layout .event-img { height: initial; max-height: initial; }`

Comment: Great. Thanks dude. Your skill makes me realise how much I've got to learn still. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! There is always lots to learn, best of luck on your journey! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Nice one. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your selector has a small typo/error. Change this:

```
.box-layout.event-img img { ... }
```

to this:

```
.box-layout .event-img img { ... }
```

The first one is looking for an image inside an element with class `box-layout` AND `event-img`. You want an image inside element with class `event-img` that is inside element with class `box-layout`. The space between the selector classes makes all the difference.

Comment: That's great,  thanks. So how do i stop the image overlapping the text?

Comment: At the moment I've unset width and height but either it overlaps, or I apply `margin-top` to the `.event-title` which doesn't work either as each image has a different height... So, whilst with some setting `margin-top: Xpx` works, others it doesn't. I need a generic way of applying space between image and text which, in this case, targeting the div class doesn't seem to achieve...

Comment: img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

Comment: Nice try, didn't work, images still overlapping text desktop... https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/